# Stop NSWindow Animator proxy animation

Tags: cocoa, core-animation

I'm animating a **NSWindow** to snap to a certain position on the screen using a **SKBounceAnimation** as the animator proxy's `setAnimations:@{@"frame":skBounceAnim}`.

As soon as I click-and-hold on the window (and begin dragging), I'd like to stop immediately this animation, so that the window follows the mouse movement, instead of continuing executing the animation.

**So far I've tried to:**

- unset the animation on mouse-down event `[window.animator setAnimations:nil]`.
- setting the animation object to nil on mouse-down event `skBounceAnimation = nil`
- applying a new, very short new animation on mouse-down event `[window.animator setFrame:(the current frame) display:YES]; [NSAnimationContent currentContent].duration = 0.01;`

All of it hasn't helped yet. Any thoughts?